# Summarizing 3 sparse matrices into one full matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have three tables, `patients`, `samples`, and `mutations`:

- `patients` table has unique rows, each with a unique `patient_id`.
- `samples` table has unique rows, each with a unique `sample_id`, but also a `patient_id` that can be found in the patients table. There may be multiple rows in the samples table with the same `patient_id`.
- `mutations` table has NON-unique rows. Each row in the mutations table contains just two columns: `gene` and `sample_id`.

I need to create a new table, call it `summary`, with `patient_id` in the first column, sample_id, followed by a column for every distinct gene in the mutations table.

Each row of the new summary table should contain

- the `patient_id` from the patients table,
- the `sample_id` from the `samples` table,
- a the number `1` in each following `gene` column for each `gene` in the `mutations` table that has a `sample_id` for the specific `patient` or a number `0` if not.

New summary table looks sort of like this:

```
patient_id, sample_id, gene A, gene B, gene C, gene D, etc
12345678,54321,1,0,0,0
23456789,65432,0,1,1,0
34567890,76543,0,0,1,0
34567890,87654,0,1,0,1
etc
```

The new summary table must have an entry, either a `0` or a `1`, for every distinct `gene` found in the `mutations` table even if there are no entries in the mutations table that have a `sample_id` belonging to the patient for a specific row.

Remember, there may be multiple samples belonging to the same patient, so the summary table could contain multiple rows for a given patient - each row for a different sample.

Thanks for any guidance - R is relatively new to me...    :)

Sample Data:

patients table:

PATIENT_ID,AGE,PARTC_CONSENTED_12_245,AGE_CURRENT,RACE,RELIGION,ETHNICITY,OS_STATUS,OS_MONTHS,PED_IND,SEX,RECURRENCE,POD_FIRST_LINE,SYSTEMIC_TREATMENT,TIME_TO_LAST_FOLLOWUP
    P-0000114,57,NO,59,White,CATHOLIC/ROMAN,Non-Spanish; non Hispanic,DECEASED,15.16,No,Female,0,Yes,gem/ox + HAI FUDR,15.16
    P-0000127,62,NO,64,White,NONE,Non-Spanish; non-Hispanic,DECEASED,14.28,No,Male,0,Yes,gem/cis,14.28
    P-0000147,40,NO,45,Black,CHRISTIAN,Non-Spanish; non-Hispanic,LIVING,38.433,No,Female,0,Yes,gem,38.45
    P-0000154,76,NO,79,White,JEWISH,Non-Spanish; non-Hispanic,DECEASED,23.145,No,Male,0,Yes,gem/cis,23.52
    P-0000159,67,NO,70,"Other Asian, including Asian, NOS and Oriental, NOS",CHRISTIAN,Non-Spanish; non-Hispanic,DECEASED,18.773,No,Female,0,Yes,gem/cis,18.78

samples table:

SAMPLE_ID,PATIENT_ID,HAS_MATCHED_NORMAL,TIME_TO_METASTASIS_MONTHS,SAMPLE_TYPE,SAMPLE_CLASS,METASTATIC_SITE,PRIMARY_SITE,ONCOTREE_CODE,GENE_PANEL,SO_COMMENTS,SAMPLE_COVERAGE,TUMOR_PURITY,MSI_COMMENT,MSI_SCORE,MSI_TYPE,INSTITUTE,SOMATIC_STATUS,AGE_AT_SEQ_REPORT,ARCHER,CVR_TMB_COHORT_PERCENTILE,CVR_TMB_SCORE,CVR_TMB_TT_COHORT_PERCENTILE,STAGE_4_DX
P-0000114-T01-IM3,P-0000114,Matched,0,Metastasis,Tumor,Lymph Node,Liver,IHCH,IMPACT341,,938,60,Not Available,0.47,Stable,MSKCC,Matched,58,NO,58.6,4.5,75.9,Yes
P-0000114-T02-IM3,P-0000114,Matched,0,Primary,Tumor,Not Applicable,Liver,IHCH,IMPACT341,,409,60,Not Available,0.26,Stable,MSKCC,Matched,59,NO,58.6,4.5,75.9,Yes
P-0000127-T01-IM3,P-0000127,Matched,0,Metastasis,Tumor,Lymph Node,Liver,IHCH,IMPACT341,,623,30,Not Available,0,Stable,MSKCC,Matched,64,NO,29.9,2.2,36,Yes
P-0000127-T02-IM3,P-0000127,Matched,0,Metastasis,Tumor,Lymph Node,Liver,IHCH,IMPACT341,,255,0,Not Available,0,Stable,MSKCC,Matched,64,NO,29.9,2.2,36,Yes
P-0000147-T01-IM3,P-0000147,Matched,25,Primary,Tumor,Not Applicable,Liver,IHCH,IMPACT341,,1051,80,MICROSATELLITE STABLE (MSS). See MSI note below.,0.17,Stable,MSKCC,Matched,41,NO,0,0,0,No
P-0000154-T01-IM3,P-0000154,Matched,0,Primary,Tumor,Not Applicable,Liver,IHCH,IMPACT341,,767,70,Not Available,1.2,Stable,MSKCC,Matched,78,NO,44.1,3.3,59.4,Yes

mutations table:

Hugo_Symbol,Tumor_Sample_Barcode
BAP1,P-0009513-T01-IM5
PDGFRA,P-0000114-T01-IM5
BAP1,P-0009513-T01-IM5
KRAS,P-0000114-T02-IM3
CDKN1B,P-0000192-T02-IM3
IDH1,P-0000327-T01-IM3
ARID1A,P-0000327-T01-IM3
DOT1L,P-0000327-T01-IM3
NOTCH4,P-0001539-T01-IM3
ABL1,P-0001539-T01-IM3
SUFU,P-0001539-T01-IM3
PBRM1,P-0000114-T01-IM3
IDH1,P-0002143-T01-IM3
KRAS,P-0002143-T01-IM3
ARID1A,P-0000114-T01-IM3
MLL3,P-0000127-T01-IM3
ERBB3,P-0000117-T01-IM3
ARID1A,P-0002211-T01-IM3
TP53,P-0003407-T01-IM5
ARID1A,P-0000127-T01-IM3
ERBB3,P-000012707-T01-IM5
STAG2,P-0003407-T01-IM5
KRAS,P-0003473-T01-IM5
PBRM1,P-0003590-T01-IM5
TET2,P-0003590-T01-IM5
IDH1,P-0003795-T01-IM5
TP53,P-0003795-T01-IM5
SPEN,P-0003795-T01-IM5

Comment: Voted to close here, as programming questions are more suited to Stack Overflow. In general, looking at dplyr and tidyr cheatsheets will help - this can be achieved by combining join and spread functions.

Comment: Please add examples on each of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick in MySQL:

`select cs.patient_id, g.*
from clynical_sample cs
inner join (
  select *
  from 
   (with cp as
      (select * from
         (select gene from mutations group by gene) c
          cross join (select sample_id from clynical_sample group by sample_id) m)
    select cp.gene, cp.sample_id, ifnull(m.id,0) id
    from cp 
    left join (select gene, sample_id, 1 id from mutations) m on m.gene=cp.gene and m.sample_id=cp.sample_id)

  pivot ( max(id) for gene in ('BAP1','PDGFRA','KRAS','CDKN1B','IDH1','ARID1A','DOT1L','NOTCH4','ABL1','PBRM1','MLL3','TET2','SPEN','CCND2','DDR2','RICTOR','SMAD4','GLI1','RASA1','MAP2K1','CSF3R','HIST1H3D','DNMT3B','CEBPA','GATA2','ARID1B','BRCA2','EPHA7','CTNNB1','EPHA5','EP300','RAF1','NF1','EGFR','NBN','INHA','CARD11','ANKRD11','ERBB3','TERT','DNMT1','ATM','RIT1','PDCD1','SMARCA4','FOXP1','DICER1','TGFBR2','PTPRS','FANCC','APC','NCOA3','NTRK1','PTPRD','NSD1','GRIN2A','SMARCB1','PTCH1','KEAP1','KDR','IRS2','PIK3R3','SUFU','STAG2','MAP3K13','SOX9','SETD2','FAT1','ZFHX3','NRAS','MAP3K1','ERBB4','JAK3','NF2','PGR','KDM6A','RPTOR','TP53','CIC','MSH2','MAP2K4','AXIN2','PTEN','XPO1','ERCC4','AXL','RNF43','DNMT3A','ERG','NOTCH2','RFWD2','IGF1R','GATA1','SMAD3','TMPRSS2','MLL','BRAF','TET1','BCOR','YAP1','HLA-A','PLCG2','CBL','IRS1','PIK3CA','POLE','LATS2','MST1','H3F3B','IRF4','AR','B2M','NCOR1','FUBP1','NOTCH3','ATR','RPS6KB2','TSC2','PIK3CG','MDM2','ROS1','TCF3','TSC1','FGFR2','FBXW7','FOXA1','MEN1','CDKN2Ap16INK4A','EPHA3','PMS1','PAK1','E2F3','PIK3CD','PLK2','MPL','RHEB','RBM10','ASXL2','MSH6','RAD21','BRIP1','PTPRT','GNA11','CDKN1A','RAD50','BRD4','STK11','ARID2','RUNX1','MTOR','JAK1','TBX3','MALT1','RYBP','MLL2','PIK3CB','SMO','AXIN1','MAPK3','VHL','JUN','KDM5A','ARID5B','AMER1','PPM1D','ASXL1','MLH1','CASP8','BARD1','DAXX','CDH1','PALB2','AKT3','RECQL4','IGF2','MED12','FLT3','HIST3H3','MST1R','EIF4A2','CREBBP','STAT5B','PHOX2B','BRCA1','ERBB2','MITF','RB1','CD79A','TMEM127','MAPK1','CDKN2A','CDKN2Ap14ARF','CSF1R','FLT4','CENPA','RPS6KA4','SRC','ERCC3','NEGR1','RET','ACVR1','SYK','ICOSLG','FYN','SOX17','ETV6','NTRK3','HIST1H1C','IDH2','CHEK1','GNAS','PPP6C','EZH2','MYCL1','SDHA','MDC1','ARAF','RAC1','KDM5C','PARP1','NKX2-1','CXCR4','SMAD2','IL7R','TGFBR1','U2AF1','SF3B1','FGFR4','ERRFI1','SMARCD1','FGFR1','EPHB1','PDPK1','FLCN','RAD54L','MGA','PPP2R1A'))
  ) g on g.sample_id = cs.sample_id;`